# How can I get Entity Framework 6 to change catalogs using MySql provider?

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, catalog

I am trying to access a legacy database using the MySql provider and EntityFramework 6.

The current structure is a different catalog for every client we have, thus I need to select a different catalog depending on the customer selected.

How would I do this using Entity Framework?